# Disable button in onActivityResult

Tags: android, listview

I have a button to take picture inside a listview inside a pageviewer.
So, in the listview's adapter, I have an onclick event to take pic.
What I want is that getting the button object to disable it in the onActivityResult ( Inside activity)
I tried to use :

```
ListView lstForm;               
View v = (View) lstForm.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

But I just access data not button.

Here is my getView() method in FormAdapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_form, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.item = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.valor = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.valor);
            holder.imgCam = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.cambutton);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        String marca = lForm.get(position).getMarca() + "\n" + lForm.get(position).getProducto();

        String valor = lForm.get(position).getCantidad();
        if (valor == null || valor.equals("null"))
            valor = "";
        holder.item.setText(marca);
        holder.valor.setText(valor);

        holder.imgCam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "elemento numero:" + position + " metricaId:" + metricaId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                takePic(TAKE_PIC_REQUEST, position, metricaId);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add a boolean flag in the objects representing your data items to indicate whether the button should be enabled or disabled - and have it enabled by default.  Then in `onActivityResult` get the corresponding item, set the flag to disabled and force the list to redraw itself.  In the `getView` method of the adapter you'd disable the button if the flag is set accordingly.

```
public class MyDataItem {
    ...
    boolean canTakePicture = true;

    ...

    public void setCanTakePicture(boolean fl) { canTakePicture = fl; }
    public boolean isCanTakePicture() { return canTakePicture; }
}
```

In `onActivityResult`:

```
ListView lstForm;               
((MyDataItem) lstForm.getItemAtPosition(position)).setCanTakePicture(false);
lstForm.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Of course, you'll need somehow to know which `position` you're dealing with - but I'm guessing you do know already.

and in `getView()`:

```
holder.item.setText(marca);
holder.valor.setText(valor);

holder.imgCam.setEnabled(lForm.get(position).isCanTakePicture()); // <-- this line added

holder.imgCam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro what do you mean by _not working_?  Your adapter extends implements the Adapter - therefore `getAdapter` would return your custom adapter.

Comment: lstForm.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); --> The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter. I must Cast lstForm.getAdapter so that it doesn't show error. but it doesn't appear to refresh list

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` is a method in the adapter - your adapter extends from some list adapter, therefore it has this method

Comment: the adapter extends : ArrayAdapter<Formulario> Let me see it I can make it work

Comment: It seems that lForms ( where the flag is false) is resetting somewhere, it always come true to the adapter. even with debug, I don't see where... Even trying like that  : adbForm = new FormsAdapter(this, 0, lForms, lMetricas.get(numTab).getId());
    lstForm.setAdapter(adbForm);

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better not to get view item from your listview, but manage (depending on item position) the button state (enable/disable) inside the getView method of your listview and call notifydatasetchanged in onActivityResult...

Comment: i can't comment with reputation below 50 :)

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            final Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                if(requestCode == TAKE_PIC_REQUEST) {
              holder.setEnabled(false); 
              holder.setClickable(false);
}  
}
```

Comment: That won't work, as `holder` is a variable local to the `getView`